# What is the difference between photons in the E-Field and the H-Field?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, relativity

It is well established that the photon is the propagator for the electromagnetic force. How are the set of photons used in the H-field behaving differently than those in the E-field? Is it different when dealing with an electromagnet versus an intrinsic magnet?

In what way do the photons need to be emitted by a bar magnet to result in a magnetic interaction? How about a charged object to interact with a charged object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual photons that represent the static Coulomb potential, so the electric field, have time polarisation and those representing the static vector potential, so the magnetic field, have spatial polarisation.

Comment: Thanks! Still a bit unclear. Do you have a reference for this so I can look more into it?

Comment: The so called off the mass shell virtual photons are just the Fourier components of the potential. For a static electric field this is the Coulomb potential $A^0$ and for a static magnetic field the vector potential $\vec A$. This leads you to my answer.@finesagan